# git revert vs. git show -R & git apply -3

Tags: git

### Problem

My git repository has a huge number of objects (nearly 600k, consisting of both text and binary files and total sum of the packfiles is 20GiB) and a `git revert` takes a very long time (around 15 minutes) to finish. `git gc`, which itself takes a longer time (around 40 minutes), didn't help.

Then I came up with an idea that I make a reverse patch of a commit of interest by `git show --binary -R <sha1> > /tmp/x`, merge-apply it to the index and the working directory by `git apply -3 /tmp/x`, and then `git commit` right after that to produce a "revert commit". It worked, and finished its job in less than 30 seconds.

### Question

What does `git revert` do exactly, and what might I miss if I use `git show --binary -R`, `git apply -3` and then `git commit` instead of the former?

I assumed the two operations were the same, but from the observation I explained above `git revert` does something much more than `git show --binary -R` then `git apply -3`.

Note that the merge conflicts are not an issue; they frequently happen and I fix them each time without problems. Also, `git apply -3` appears to detect them correctly.

auto-gc is turned off.

**Update**

I discovered one problem; if a reverse patch contains a file deletion and the content of that file differs from the patch, `git apply -3` prints `error: <filename>: patch does not apply` and exits *without touching the index*. `git revert` sets such files to a conflicted state with `deleted by them` (reported by `git status`) in such cases.

### Background

I've used git as a backup system for my entire Linux system, whose distribution is Linux From Scratch. Being skeptical of package management systems, I'm playing around with my OS by manually managing packages using git. I make a pair of commits for each package I install to take snapshot of before/after installation. Those pairs enable me to uninstall desired packages by `git revert <the-commit-after-install>`.

I know git is not supposed to be used as a backup system. I use `metastore` to store metadata (owners/permissions, etc) in a binary file (which regularly causes conflicts on reverts). I chose git because it was widely used and seemed stable. Also "being skeptical" plays a part of choosing non-backup software for a backup purpose.
I heard git is not good at handling binary files, especially big ones. The truth is that it does decent job against binary files, until I installed TeXLive 2016, which is the second revision of TeXLive on my OS.

In most cases I use `git revert` when upgrading a package. First, I `git revert` an old package to uninstall it. Then I "fresh-install" a new package so that a history for each file doesn't get convoluted (a chain of modifies makes it harder when I really want to uninstall it). I cannot leave the shell until `git revert` finishes because I have to quickly install the now-missing new package right after that, or risk the stability of my OS.

Comment: I thought that `git revert` _adds_ one or more commits which undo the changes from previous commits, but maybe there is another usage I don't know.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `git apply -3` updates the index and the working directory. `commit`ing right after that produces (apparently) the same result.

Comment: I realized we can't use `git revert --abort` with show-apply approach. By re-applying a forward patch and a bit of manual struggle, we could achieve the same result, but not tested.

Comment: `git revert` and `git cherry-pick` are almost the same command (built in part from the same source), although details depend on your specific Git version. It's not immediately obvious why you saw that much difference in performance, but my first suspicion is that your particular git version implements both using something that invokes `git gc --auto` and you just got lucky / unlucky enough to have the one slow auto-gc apply to your revert.

Comment: @torek I'm using v2.8.1. I measured the time of `git gc` and it took 40 minutes. Auto-gc is turned off (`git config gc.auto` prints `0` and `git gc --auto` exits immidiately). I'll try the latest version of git (v2.9.3) to see if there are any differences.

Comment: As of v2.9.3, the same problem occurs.

Comment: Interesting.  Does `git show -R` (without `--binary`) take very long?  (And, any re-packing operation will tend to be slow with big repositories.  Tweaking `core.bigFileThreshold` could help but if there are many small files it may still be slow.  There are other config items new to me (I have not looked closely since before Git 2.0) such as `core.deltaBaseCacheLimit` that might be useful as well.

Comment: @torek `git show -R` with or without `--binary` finishes quickly (in rare cases it takes ~30sec much). I suspect tweaking git configs only affects `git gc` but not `git revert`. For example, `core.bigFileThreshold` disables packing large files which means more loose objects. I heard git operates slower against more loose files. Also, I don't mind `git gc` taking a long time since I do it overnight or while I'm out (via ssh, etc.) I'll edit the question to clarify why `git revert` has to finish quickly.

Comment: At this point I'm out of off-hand suggestions.  It's clear enough why this approach isn't used in general (uninstalling package X requires knowledge Git lacks as to whether packages Y and Z depend on X, for instance) but not at all obvious why `git revert` is that much slower than show-pipe-to-reverse-apply (or reverse-show-pipe-to-apply, same thing).

Comment: @torek Thanks for suggestions anyway. I handle dependencies manually so it's OK. I by no means wish this method would be popular (just to clarify ;)